# How can I address the autocorrelation in my glmm?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, autocorrelation, binary-data, glmm

I am looking at effect of diet on breeding success of birds. For 8 years, I have breeding success (number of chicks fledged / number of eggs laid), as well as Frequency of Occurrence (FO) of Fish in diet samples collected.

Initially, my dataframe (df) was set up in 4 columns ("Year", "number_eggs", "number_fledged", and "FO_Fish"), and 8 rows (one row for each year). The model I used was a binomial glm for proportional data:

`BS <- cbind(df$number_fledged, df$number_eggs-df$number_fledged)`

`mod <- glm(BS ~ Fish_FO, data = df, family = binomial)`

After discussions with fellow students, it was suggested I try a glmm instead, where my response variable is binary ("fledged" and "not fledged"). Instead of having 1 row per year, I would have between 200 and 300 rows per year, one for each egg laid across the 8 years. As Fish_FO is just one measure for each year, I would have identical values of Fish_FO for each of the data points within individual years. Years would be used as a random effect to deal with autocorrelation issues of repeat measures.

With "BS" now being the name of a binary response variable, the resulting model is now.

`M2 <- glmer(BS ~ Fisheries_FO + (1|Year), data = df, family = binomial(link = logit))`

All the model diagnostics look much better for the glmm than they did for the glm, except that running acf shows that I have huge autocorrelation in the data.

I read in a thread that a random effect can only address temporal or spatial autocorrelation where point 1 is closer to point 2 than it is to point 3 (lag effect).

My questions are:
(1) Is it acceptable to run a glmm with my data, as had been suggested?
(2) What is the name of the autocorrelation structure I am dealing with (I don't know the term, and so google searchers for solutions are difficult).
(3) Is there a way to address the autocorrelation structure of my data when running a glmm?

Comment: How exactly did you "run acf"? Are you inspecting residuals from the `M2` model fit or just the univariate `BS` response?

Comment: @ AdamO, I run acf(residuals(M2))

Comment: You say you have approx 200 rows per year, one per each fish egg across the years. But unless these are sorted in chronological sequence, `acf` has no way how to rank observations in time, and what interval in time. It sounds like the results are spuriously positive.

Comment: So the years are sorted in chronological order, if this is what you mean?

Comment: No. I'm just not sure you're thinking about this correctly, the mixed model would be justified if you were modeling individual-level effects such as the outcomes of a particular fish over multiple points in time. This is an ecological study. If year is the finest measurement of time available to you, you should scrap the mixed model and adjust for year as a fixed effect. If you have more granular measures of time, you should consider adjusting for time with a flexible smoothing procedure to reduce the dimensionality of dummy encoding, but achieve approximately the same level of predictiveness.

Comment: hm.. interesting. So you mean I dont actually need the random effects term ? I thought this was needed to account for multiple measurements within each year.

Comment: You do need to account for "year" as its the so called "period" effect of your cohort. But with only 8 years to account for, adjusting for year as a dummy variable fixed effect is a more powerful analysis and it's easier to interpret. Random effects are preferred when the number of dummy encoded variables to adjust for a clustering-term grow to be a noticeable fraction of the sample size.